# There are extra whitespaces produced by `echo` command

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

> environment: macOS 10.14
>
> shell: zsh

There are some lines of code from the book 'The Linux Command Line'

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ -n $1 ]]; do
        if [[ -r $1 ]]; then
                max_word=
                max_len=0
                for i in $(strings $1); do
                        len=$(echo $i | wc -c)
                        if (( len > max_len )); then
                                max_len=$len
                                max_word=$i
                        fi
                done
                echo "$1: '$max_word' ($max_len characters)"
        fi
        shift
done
```

I ran the code with the command

```
hello hello
```

`hello` is the file which contains the code and is executable. The program is simple. However, the output is:

```
hello: 'max_len=$len' (      13 characters)
```

You can see some extra whitespace after left `(`. I don't know why and didn't get any solution through google.

Comment: Your version of `wc` is left-padding its output, which the quoted expansion of `max_len` preserves.

Comment: A nitpick - you may be running `zsh` on your command line, but the shebang says bash inside the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why spawn the extra process? `len=${#i}` should give you the length of a string more efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

Does not happen on Linux but I bet is `wc -c` that on Mac is printing " 13" instead of "13".
One way to solve is to change

```
len=$(echo $i | wc -c)
```

to

```
len=($(echo $i | wc -c))
```

This workaround uses array syntax, the " 13" will be interpreted as an array so bash will parse "( 13)" that gives a ["13"] array. `len` will contain an array but when used as a normal variable bash will use the first element, in this case the stripped version of `wc -c` output.

Comment: This is a bad workaround. Don't use `wc` at all, and the implementation-specific output of `wc` isn't a problem.

Comment: Agreeing with @paul-hodges suggestion. Usually wc is used for lines, in this case I'm not sure there's an easy bash workaround.

Comment: Another option for Mac users is to use the GNU version of `wc`, which is `gwc` on the Mac, if installed via `brew install coreutils`.